# Unable to display common name from combobox bearing abbreviated names

Tags: xpages

I am retrieving values of combobox from @dblookup formula. This formula returns name values in abbreviated format. But, I want to display these name values as Common Names [CN] in combobox. But while saving to the document, the selected value should be saved in abbreviated format.

I tried accomplishing this task using custom converters, but all in vain. Is it possible to do through this way ?
Please help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selection fields (combo, radio, checkbox) support pipe aliasing. In your select items formula, loop through the @DbLookup results and turn each one into an aliased string:

```
var result = [];
var abbreviatedNames = @DbLookup(...;
for (var i = 0; i < abbreviatedNames.length; i++) {
  var eachName = abbreviatedNames[i];
  result.push(@Name("[CN]",eachName) + "|" + eachName);
}
return result;
```

The user will be able to select a common name, but the actual value stored will be the abbreviated name.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah! That works like a charm. Very nice use of aliasing. You saved my day.

Comment: How can we accomplish the same thing with the Text box (Edit box) ? If I am taking value from dominoNABNamepicker.